# How do I decide where to put the Asterisk?

Tags: c, pointers

will these lines do the same? If not, what's the difference? How do I decide where to put the asterisk?

```
#define OUT1 *((portptr ) SIGDATA_ADR)

#define OUT1 ((portptr *) SIGDATA_ADR)
```

Ok, sorry for the vague problem description.
What I'm trying to do is a function that continuously reads the value of two switches, makes a XOR, and puts it on a LED ramp.

My program looks like this; and it should work.

```
typedef unsigned char *port8ptr; 

#define OUT *((port8ptr) 0x400) 
#define IN1 *((port8ptr) 0x600) 
#define IN2 *((port8ptr) 0x601) 


 void DipSwitchEor( void ) 

{ 
  while( 1 )
  { 
    OUT = IN1 ^ IN2; 
  } 
}
```

So I'm just curious if I could have written `#define OUT ((port8ptr *) 0x400)` instead. I'm getting mixed answers.

Comment: I have edited your tags to include the (presumed) language. Please always add an appropriate tag when asking such language-specific questions; it also increases the probability of visitors knowing the particular language you are asking about will notice your question.

Comment: What is this supposed to be? A function pointer or is it using some kind of macro? What are you actually attempting to do? I can't syntactically make sense of it.

Comment: Neither of this lines actually make sense. Could you please expose your original problem, instead?

Comment: Macros and pointers go not mix too well. Avoid them

Comment: I've updated the main post now.

Comment: This code is likely to fail if compiler optimisation is applied.  `port8ptr` should be defined thus: `typedef volatile unsigned char* port8ptr;`

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of `OUT1` and `OUT2` are not semantically equivalent.

- In the first case  `SIGDATA_ADR` is cast to a pointer type `portptr`, and then dereferenced, so the argument to `OUT1()` in the first case is the data pointed to by SIGDATA_ADR.  This makes sense and is likely the correct semantics - given you subsequent example of the use case, it is certainly correct.
- In the second case, `(portptr*)` is a pointer-to-pointer, and the argument to `OUT1()` in the second case `SIGDATA_ADR` cast to a pointer-to-pointer - which seems unlikely.

Note that in the first case the `*` is the *dereference operator*, and the second it is not an operator but a *data type modifier*.  They are not the same thing - they just happen to be represented by the same character - context is everything; understanding that probably makes determining which is correct far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between these two macro definitions

```
#define OUT *((port8ptr) 0x400)
#define OUT ((port8ptr*) 0x400)
```

The first one first makes a `port8ptr` (cast) that points at memory address `0x400`, then it dereferences this pointer (`*` operator outside of parentheses) to yield the `unsigned char` that is located at memory address `0x400`.

The second one makes a pointer to a `port8ptr` that points at memory address `0x400`. The result has the same type as a variable `foo` declared with `port8ptr* foo;`. That is, the result is a *double pointer to an `unsigned char`*, the char being located in memory wherever the pointer stored at memory address `0x400` is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to tell what various C declaration constructs mean, I think that you should try http://cdecl.org. It is also a utility that you can install on your computer. Probably what you want with your example is the code below, assuming that 0x600, 0x601 and 0x400 are the addresses of your registers:

```
void dip_switch() {
    unsigned char *in1 = 0x600;
    unsigned char *in2 = 0x601;
    unsigned char *out = 0x400;
    *out = (*in1) ^ (*in2);
}
```

Using `#define`s will only bite you in a situation like this. You should probably steer away from it.